# Make Grid System Responsive (One on left and two on right)

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive

I got this grid system from my previous question that was answered by Andy Hoffman. Here is the grid system:

```css
#showroom {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    height: 250px;
}

#boxOne {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

#boxTwo {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#boxThree {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#showroom > * {
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="showroom">
    <div id="boxOne"></div>
    <div id="boxTwo"></div>
    <div id="boxThree"></div>
</div>
```

My question would be how to make this grid system responsive at under **750 pixels** (`@media screen and (max-width: 750px){}`). It should look like this in the responsive version:

[image]

Is this possible with this Grid System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the media query, reset rules `grid-column` and `grid-row` by setting parameter `revert`.

> The `revert` CSS keyword reverts the cascaded value of the property from its current value to the value the property would have had if no changes had been made by the current style origin to the current element. Thus, it resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or to the default value established by the user agent's stylesheet (or by user styles, if any exist).

```css
#showroom {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    height: 250px;
}

#boxOne {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

#boxTwo {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#boxThree {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#showroom > * {
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    #boxOne,
    #boxTwo,
    #boxThree {
        grid-column: revert;
        grid-row: revert;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="showroom">
    <div id="boxOne"></div>
    <div id="boxTwo"></div>
    <div id="boxThree"></div>
</div>
```